# FFT in Python: formatting 1-D diffraction Fourier transform

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm relatively new to Python and the FFT function.  I'm trying to use the numpy.fft.fft() function to transform a square pulse (1-D diffraction slit function) to a sinc function (1-D diffraction pattern), and make the output plot identical to the analytical transform of the square pulse, given by the equation:

> F(u) = sin(πau)/(πu)

However, I am having trouble formatting the FFT to make it look identical to the analytical function.  This is my minimal working code:

```
a = 40.0  # slit width
N = 5000  # sample points
T = 100.0  # sample spacing
x = np.linspace(-T/2.0,T/2.0,N)

y = np.piecewise(x,[abs(x)>a/2,abs(x)<=a/2],[0,1])  # make 1-D square pulse array

dx = x[1] - x[0]
yf = np.fft.fft(y) * dx  # Fourier transform
xf = np.fft.fftfreq(N,d=dx)
xf = np.fft.fftshift(xf)
yf = np.fft.fftshift(yf)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(xf,yf)

f = np.sin(np.pi*a*x)/(np.pi*x)  # analytical transform function
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x,f)
plt.show()
```

I think I need to adjust the frequencies for the FFT, but I'm not sure.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You have a discrete signal with finite length.  When you use the FFT to
compute the Fourier transform of that signal, you are assuming that the
signal is *periodic*.  That is, your signal is not a single rectangular pulse; it is a *repeating* pulse.  The analytic result that applies in
this case is the *periodic sinc function* (also known as the *aliased sinc function*
or the *Dirichlet function*), one form of which is

```
f(x) = sin(n*x/2) / (n*sin(x/2))
```

This function is available as [`scipy.special.diric`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.special.diric.html).  Just recently I
added an example to the docstring of `diric` to show exactly what you
are asking.  Here's the example.  (It won't appear in a released version
of scipy until version 0.17.)

---

Standard imports:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import special
```

Create a small rectangular pulse for the demonstration:

```
>>> m = 8
>>> k = 3
>>> x = np.zeros(m)
>>> x[:k] = 1
```

Use the FFT to compute the Fourier transform of `x`, and
inspect the magnitudes of the coefficients:

```
>>> np.abs(np.fft.fft(x))
array([ 3.        ,  2.41421356,  1.        ,  0.41421356,  1.        ,
        0.41421356,  1.        ,  2.41421356])
```

Now find the same values (up to sign) using `diric`.  We multiply
by `k` to account for the different scaling conventions of
`numpy.fft.fft` and `diric`:

```
>>> theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, m, endpoint=False)
>>> k * special.diric(theta, k)
array([ 3.        ,  2.41421356,  1.        , -0.41421356, -1.        ,
       -0.41421356,  1.        ,  2.41421356])
```

Comment: Ah, I see: so the finite length is the problem, but with the analytic function?  Or both the FFT and analytic function?  Also, when I tried implementing your code, I got a few extra values using the diric.  Do you happen to know why this is?  Thanks so much for your help!