# Scipy FFT accuracy is much worse than analytical FT of a box function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I'm trying to check the accuracy of the scipy Fast Fourier Transform function using a box function which has a defined analytical expression, a sinc function. The result of the scipy FFT gives values that are orders of magnitude off from when the sinc function result would be close to 0.

In my graph below, I've plotted the box function and the bounds I'm passing it to create the box and in the second plot, I show the scipy fft and the analytical equivalent, a sinc function, in log scale.

[image: Box function and FFT plot]

The 'close to 0' computed values do change as a function of total number of samples, but I quickly require enormous amounts of time to push the values down towards the analytical values.
For example:

- 2^15 samples, 1.2s, 12 orders of magnitude difference
- 2^18 samples, 1.9s, 11 order of magnitude difference
- 2^22 samples, 14.8s, 11 orders of magnitude difference

How can I improve the accuracy of this FFT?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft, fftshift, fftfreq
from matlabplot import pyplot as plt

num = 2**18 # sample spacing
span = 2 # seconds
period = span/num #1.0 / 1e9
box_test = np.linspace(-period*num/2, period*num/2, num, endpoint= False, dtype='clongdouble')
shifted_box = ifftshift(box_test)
def rect(x):
    return np.where(np.abs(x)<=0.5, 1 + 0j, 0 + 0j)


y = rect(box_test)
y_shift = rect(shifted_box)
yf = fft(y_shift, norm='backward')
xf = fftfreq(num, period)


#plotting
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(20,10))

plt.grid()
ax1.plot(box_test, y)
ax2.plot(fftshift(xf),  fftshift(np.absolute(yf))*span/num, '-.', label='fft')
ax2.plot(fftshift(xf), fftshift(np.absolute(np.sinc(xf))), 'r--', label = 'sinc')
ax1.set_title('box function')
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('arb units')
ax2.set_yscale('log')
ax2.set_xlim([-20,20])
# ax2.set_ylim([-10,10])
ax2.set_title("analytical and numerical simulation Optical homodyne PSD")
ax2.set_xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
ax2.set_ylabel("theoretical detector output (arb units)")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The FFT computes a DFT, not an FT. Remember that. The discrete version of the transform does not translate identically from the continuous world. Your input signal is periodic, and the output is too. The DFT of your box function is not a perfectly windowed sinc function.

Comment: Then I guess a better question would be, how does one attempt to improve the input signal such that it would better approach the the perfectly windowed sinc function? 
I have been reading alot of threads with regards to zero padding, which I assume means that you just add more zeros around your signal, such that it's "harder" for the DFT to 'assume' periodicity [link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/47851090/21538356

Comment: The periodicity is always there, but as you add more padding, the copies of your window are further apart, and thus will influence each other less, in a manner of speaking.

Comment: So I added a large amount of zero padding (factor of 250) and I saw little to no reduction in the difference between the troughs. I don't think the periodicity is playing a large part in the calculation of the values

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792597/fft-in-python-formatting-1-d-diffraction-fourier-transform/31793705#31793705

Answer (score 0):

A FFT or DFT does a circular convolution (not a linear convolution) against a window function the length of the FFT.  A circular convolution wraps the data around the FFT.  Since a Sinc function has infinite non-zero "tails", it will wrap around its tails around the FFT result, additively, a near-infinite number of times (to the limits of numerical noise).  A longer FFT means the part of the tail that wraps around with be farther from center, and thus lower in magnitude.

If you want a "box-like" function that results in a finite width windowed Sinc after being FFT'd, you need to take the inverse FT of the desired windowed Sinc.  But note that that "box-like" function will have infinite support (it will be longer than the FFT, or it will be wrapped around itself when using a finite length IDFT).

This is because a property of the FT is that functions with finite support in one domain have infinite support in the other.  And DFT and FFT implementations can only handle finite length vectors.

Comment: So I do have a question, I understand that DFT and FFT implementations arent a true FT since it cannot do a full finite to infinite support or vice versa with a IFT(i'm assuming the latter), but why/how would the IFFT of a windowed Sinc have infinite support even though it's discretized?

And more importantly, what **should** I expect from the FFT of a box function? Should I expect more accuracy than what I have or can I calculate a lower bound of accuracy as a function of my input parameters? This SO question was just supposed to be proof of concept and now I'm learning how naive I was...

Answer (score 0):

So after some more digging into my code and comparing against [Warren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792597/fft-in-python-formatting-1-d-diffraction-fourier-transform/31793705#31793705)

I was able to figure out that the generation of my box function was not identical across my time axis. i.e[ (-2,1), (-1,1), (0,1), (1,1), (2,0)] I think this is what caused my values to be not as close to 0.

I was able to now replicate the numerical/analytical forms with the use of zero-padding and proper generation. I think it wouldn't occur normally if you set your time to start at 0, but for my purposes I needed it to be mirrored across 0.

[*Sucessful plot*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSkxn.png)

To future viewers,
Best of luck with your FFT understanding!